# Difference between HSQL: and mem: in hsqldb

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am new to hibernate and java programming in general, I just want to know the difference between an in-memory(mem:) server and an hsql: connection. I know that with in-memory it is automatically started. Is there a way to auto start the hsql: connection when the application starts?

Comment: In memory database is just that, the entire database is kept in memory, once you stop the JVM, all the contents of the database is lost. The server mode acts more like a common database, where there is some kind of server process running which you can connect to.  The process could be running locally or remotely. This allows for multiple users to connect to the database. There is also the single user/file mode, which doesn't require the database server, but persists it's content to the disk, but only one connection can be established to it.

Comment: my app will be making multiple connections so do you suggest using server mode? Also one more question, will server mode work because this is a standalone application with no internet connection so everything has to be hosted locally.

Comment: 1- Yes.  If you want to have multiple, simultaneous connections, you need to be running in server mode. 2- No, it won't make any difference, so long as the database server process is run locally

Comment: You can have multiple connections from your app to an in-memory mem: database, but he database is exclusively used for your app. The hsql: mode allows you to connect to the database from your app as well as from other applications. The server can run on the same machine or on a different machine.